# Selenium: Element not getting child element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am doing a selenium automation test where i get a list of webelements then get the child elements of each of of them. but unfortunately when i do it, it only gets the child elements of the first element from the list which is weird. can anyone point on where went wrong? Thanks.

```
@Override
public void performTest() {
    performAction();
    try {
        for (WebElement element : search_rows) {
            System.out.println(element.getAttribute("class"));
            System.out.println(element);
            assertElements(element, Constants.Selectors.AMITY_RESULT_ONE);
            assertElements(element, Constants.Selectors.AMITY_RESULT_TWO);
            assertElements(element, Constants.Selectors.AMITY_RESULT_THREE);
        }

        WebElement nextpage = WebDriverUtils.findElementByCssSelector(
                driver, Constants.Selectors.AMITY_NEXT_PAGE);
        WebDriverUtils.scrollToElement(driver, nextpage,
                WebDriverUtils.BY_JAVASCRIPT);
        nextpage.click();
        performTest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void performAction() {
    try {
        WebElement searchpage = WebDriverUtils.findElementByXpath(driver,
                Constants.Selectors.AMITY_SEARCHED_ITEMS);
        search_rows = searchpage.findElements(By
                .xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_SEARCH_WRAPPER));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void assertElements(WebElement element, String constant) {
    search_result = element.findElement(By.xpath(constant));
    System.out.println(search_result.getAttribute("class"));
    System.out.println(search_result);

    System.out.println(search_result.findElement(By
            .xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_FIRST_CHOICE)));
    comparetext = search_result.findElement(
            By.xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_FIRST_CHOICE)).getText();
    compareText(combo.getBeds(), comparetext);

    System.out.println(search_result.findElement(By
            .xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_SECOND_CHOICE)));
    comparetext = search_result.findElement(
            By.xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_SECOND_CHOICE)).getText();
    compareText(combo.getBaths(), comparetext);

    System.out.println(search_result.findElement(By
            .xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_THIRD_CHOICE)));
    comparetext = search_result.findElement(
            By.xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_THIRD_CHOICE)).getText();
    compareText(combo.getCarparks(), comparetext);

    System.out.println(search_result.findElement(By
            .xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_NAME)));
    comparetext = search_result.findElement(
            By.xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_NAME)).getText();
    containsText(combo.getSuburb(), comparetext);

    if (combo.getPrice() != null) {
        System.out.println(search_result.findElement(By
                .xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_PRICE)));
        comparetext = search_result.findElement(
                By.xpath(Constants.Selectors.AMITY_PRICE)).getText();
        if (!comparetext.equals("Contact Agent")) {
            comparetext = parsePrice(comparetext);
            comparePrice(combo.getPrice().substring(2), comparetext);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the constants:

```
    public static final String AMITY_SEARCHED_ITEMS = "//div[@class='content-sidebar-wrap']";
    public static final String AMITY_SEARCH_WRAPPER = "//div[@class='searches-wrapper']";

    public static final String AMITY_RESULT_ONE = "//div[contains(@class, 'searchresultbox1')]";
    public static final String AMITY_RESULT_TWO = "//div[contains(@class, 'searchresultbox2')]";
    public static final String AMITY_RESULT_THREE = "//div[contains(@class, 'searchresultbox3')]";

    public static final String AMITY_FIRST_CHOICE = "(//div[@class='searchinfo']//span)[1]";
    public static final String AMITY_SECOND_CHOICE = "(//div[@class='searchinfo']//span)[2]";
    public static final String AMITY_THIRD_CHOICE = "(//div[@class='searchinfo']//span)[3]";

    public static final String AMITY_NAME = "//p[@class='p-searchname']";
    public static final String AMITY_PRICE = "//div[@class='search-wrapp']//div[@class='searchprice']//span[@class='spn-search-price']//span[@class='searchprice']";

    public static final String AMITY_NEXT_PAGE = ".pagination-next > a:nth-child(1)";
```

Thank you. I really need to solve this quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath beginning with `//` is global, even if you execute it from the context of another element.

Try using `.//` instead to limit it to the element's children.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the .// thingy! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that :-

1. you have collected a list of WebElements in search_rows object by degugging the code or by evaluating it's selector in any web-browser's console
2. the elements succeeding the first element are not hidden.

Or instead of iterating over a list of WebElements simply use numeric predicate in your selectors if the child elements share the same selector.